# changing $ sign with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll

Well i'm trying to make Masonry work with infinite-scroll, and i found the official `appended` method (http://desandro.github.io/masonry/demos/infinite-scroll.html) and tried to make it work on my code. but i needed to change some of the `$` to `jQuery` and now it's working as masonry but the infinte scroll still not working, and i'm wondering if i forgot a dollar sign to change to `jQuery` from my code, **Please help me**

```
<script >
  jQuery(function(){

    var $container = jQuery('ul.products');

    $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
      $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: 'li.product',
        columnWidth : 295,
    isFitWidth: true,
        gutterWidth : 2
      });
    });

    $container.infinitescroll({
      navSelector  : '#page-nav-woo',    // selector for the paged navigation 
      nextSelector : '.next',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
      itemSelector : 'li.product',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
      loading: {
          finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
          img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
        }
      },
      // trigger Masonry as a callback
      function( newElements ) {
        // hide new items while they are loading
        var $newElems = jQuery( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
        // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
          // show elems now they're ready
          $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
          $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
        });
      }
    );

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you just change all $ to jQuery and see what happens?

Comment: Your code looks fine, are you linking to the `Masonry` jQuery plugin?

Comment: @AndyHolmes tried that, and it breaks the everything ( i mean the masonry)

Comment: @Nunners Yes, i'm trying after the scroll does its jobs to call masonry again so it rearrange all the products... but it's not working :(

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: @Nunners where should i look? i have firebug with DOM enabled but i don't know where to look for errors, i'm new at this :(

Comment: +1 for your jquery dollar ($) sign..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok the solution for my problem is like this:

1.i installed the wp-plugin

2.for callback section added:

```
 var $newElems = jQuery( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
        // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
          // show elems now they're ready
          $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
          $container.append( $newElems ).masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
        });
```

3.behavior: Masonry

And it works like a charm! Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can wrap your script in a closure:

```
(function($) {
    // i can use $ instead of jQuery
} (jQuery));
```

or

```
(function(jQuery) {
    // i can use jQuery instead of $
} ($));
```